# ggplot2: incorrect values on y-axis when using bar plot and stat = 'identity'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I work with an NBA dataset which is obtainable here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3nv38jjo5dxcl6/nba_2013.csv?dl=0

I load the libraries/dataset and do a necessary transformation with the age variable:

```
library(tidyverse)
nba <- read_csv("nba_2013.csv")
nba.new = nba %>% 
  mutate(age2 = case_when(age <= 25 ~ 'young',age > 25 & age < 30 ~ 'prime', TRUE ~ 'old'))
```

Now I want to create a barplot that displays the total amount of minutes played (variable: 'mp') for four different teams, categorized by 'young', 'prime' and 'old' players. Though the problem is that the values on the y-axis are incorrect. Here is the output:

```
nba.new %>% 
  filter(bref_team_id %in% c('OKC', 'ORL', 'NOP', 'SAS')) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(bref_team_id, mp, fill = age2), stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[nba_plot_wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abzOQ.png)

For example, young players on the team 'NOP' should have a way higher amount of total minutes played (exactly 14638). I create this output to show what values should be displayed on the y-axis:

```
nba.new %>%
  filter(bref_team_id %in% c('OKC', 'ORL', 'NOP', 'SAS')) %>% 
  group_by(bref_team_id, age2) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(mp, na.rm = T))
```

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   bref_team_id [4]
   bref_team_id age2  total
   <chr>        <chr> <dbl>
 1 NOP          old      51
 2 NOP          prime  4930
 3 NOP          young 14638
 4 OKC          old    2820
 5 OKC          prime  3011
 6 OKC          young 13375
 7 ORL          old    3044
 8 ORL          prime  2637
 9 ORL          young 12662
10 SAS          old    8369
11 SAS          prime  6431
12 SAS          young  4386
```

I can create the plot that I want when I use the preceding code and continue it with a ggplot command:

```
nba.new %>%
  filter(bref_team_id %in% c('OKC', 'ORL', 'NOP', 'SAS')) %>% 
  group_by(bref_team_id, age2) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(mp, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(bref_team_id, total, fill = age2), stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

Output:
[nba_plot_correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwqG4.png)

Why are both plots different? Shouldn't the first plot also display the total amount of minutes played in each category ('young', 'prime', 'old') for each team because of the `stat = 'identity'` command? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat = "identity"` means use the numbers exactly as they are - not "add them up".

In a simpler plot `stat = "identity"` numbers are added up by the default `position = "stack"`, but it is the stacking that effectively adds the observations. When you override the default with `position = "dodge"`, the bars are no longer stacked so no addition takes place.

Summarizing the data as you do with `dplyr` is a good way to achieve your goal. Another option is `geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge", fun = sum)` (thanks to @teunbrand in comments).

(If you stick with `stat = "identity"` you may want to switch to `geom_col`, which is the same as `geom_bar` but with `stat = "identity"` as the default.)

Comment: Just want to mention that Instead of summarizing with dplyr, you can also do `geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge", fun = sum)`.

Comment: Thank you! One follow up question: If ```stat = 'identity'``` uses the numbers exactly as they are, then what is the y-axis displaying in the first plot?

Comment: It probably overplots every observation/row atop oneanother. You can get more details with `layer_data(your_plot_object)`.